# Git clone failed with "refs/heads/master does not point to a valid object"

Tags: git, git-clone

```
C:\Users\xxx\temp>git clone D:\userdata\Dropbox\gitrepo\main.git
Cloning into 'main'...
error: unable to find 0fb6364a712239ae87e4abb35e155a04e960c788
error: refs/heads/master does not point to a valid object!
done.
error: Trying to write ref HEAD with nonexistent object 0fb6364a712239ae87e4abb3
5e155a04e960c788
fatal: Cannot update the ref 'HEAD'.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

My git repo is stored in dropbox, on my own computer this command works fine, but on another computer it gives me the above error. Any ideas? (of course the repo is synchronized)

Thanks.

Comment: Ouch.  I'm not sure it's a good idea to store your git repo in dropbox.  This smells like something is not in sync though.  Like the revision was created on the one machine, but hasn't propagated to the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause of this problem is dropbox does not syn my repo fully due to write privilege, not Git problem.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you have not the privilege of writing git files.

Comment: Guesses are not answers - try asking the question asker things like this is in the comments if you only suspect what might be wrong.